# Android WebView shows html instead of the pdf or document

Tags: android, pdf, webview, xamarin.android, google-docs

I have a webview with javascript enabled and I'm attempting to display pdf, docs, etc... using google docs view url.  The problem is that the webview is rendering html instead of the doc. I should mention that this also occurs with a url to a pdf or doc from my dropbox account.

```
string pdf = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SGFAxaYSA2wBvKCKL89rYG4yEZIJVIJ2lY-1G7IF6g4/edit?usp=sharing";
webViewcontent.LoadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

This is what is showing:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the url you are looking for is...

```
 string url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SGFAxaYSA2wBvKCKL89rYG4yEZIJVIJ2lY-1G7IF6g4/edit?usp=sharing";
 string myUrl = string.Format("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={0}", url);
 webViewcontent.LoadUrl(myUrl);
```

This will work without the user having a google account.

However, since your url is using https it may require authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
string pdf = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SGFAxaYSA2wBvKCKL89rYG4yEZIJVIJ2lY-1G7IF6g4/edit?usp=sharing";
webViewcontent.LoadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

the final url of this will be `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=**https://docs.google.com/document/d/**1SGFAxaYSA2wBvKCKL89rYG4yEZIJVIJ2lY-1G7IF6g4/edit?usp=sharing`, I think you want to remove everything except for the document id.

Comment: I updated my question to include more info.  This also occurs with a public link to a pdf or doc from my dropbox account so I believe the path including id is needed in order to resolve the files location.

Comment: From using this site: https://docs.google.com/viewer It seems like this issue is in the browser also? Can't you just put the regular url of a google doc instead of using this link?

Comment: this site has the same issue? https://docs.google.com/gview I have a feeling this is meant to be used in an iframe or something?